# How do you test a nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, command-line, nuget

I am producing a nuget package (some c# dlls that are then built into a nuget package and then uploaded to our nuget server)

I would like to have a way to test the package before I bother uploading it to a server.

I have a test project that has the package installed

Is there a way (in command line etc) to uninstall the release package from the project, and install a candidate package from the local machine in its place? (to test that the new package build is actually good?).

It would be good to have a one click update and restore of this candidate package too, so if I do a code change in my code thats being packaged, I can just have a one-click "build -> package candidate package -> restore candidate package on the test project".

In short: I change code in my package. click a button, then just hit F5 in the test project and it runs with the latest code changes.

Comment: Don't know if there's something built in, but you could just do a `dotnet add package $package $version` in a PowerShell script.

Comment: Hi matt, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

**AFAK**, to realize this, you have to modify the `PackageVersion` node to make such nuget package unique every time.

**Assume** that your lib project and main project are all new-sdk projects.

**1)** Add such node under the csproj of the class library project and make the `PackageVersion` unique. Also [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65945371/how-do-i-manage-local-nuget-packages-safely):

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.0-re-$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyyMMddHHmm'))</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**2)** change your main project's csproj file to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Lib" Version="1.0.0-*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It will use the latest version of the nuget under the nuget package source.

**3)** if you modify the lib project and then finish it, please right-click on the lib project **Properties**-->**Pack** to generate the new version.

**4)** then build the main project first, and then you can use the latest changed nuget package's code on the main project.

[image]

**And** if you want to restore to use the previous version of the nuget package, there is no way but you only have to install that version manually under **Nuget Package Management**.